# How to show checkbox selected values in the same laravel view before submitting the form?

Tags: laravel, checkbox

I have `create.blade.php` view. And that view showing a table with checkbox in each row. Now I want to show the checked row on the same view next to this table. Till now what I am getting the all the checked values but how can show it the same view before sending any post request to the server.

Here is some code-

```
@if(count($movies) > 0)
  <div class="table-responsive"> 
    <table class="table table-striped table-hover" data-toggle="dataTable" 
    data-form="deleteForm">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th></th>
        <th scope="col">Name</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    <label>Select movies</label>
    @foreach($movies as $movie)
    <tr>
      <td>
        <input class="form-check" type="checkbox" name="movie_cb" id=" . 
          {{$movie->id}}" value="{{$movie->name}}">
      </td>
      <td>{{$infeedVideo->name}}</td>
    </tr>
    @endforeach
    </tbody>
    </table>
@else
  <div class="text-center">
    <hr>
    <p class="text-center">No movies found</p>
    </div>
@endif
```

app.blade.php

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   $(document).ready(function() {
   $("#showCBs").click(function(){
     var favorite = [];
     $.each($("input[name='movie_cb']:checked"), function(){                          
     favorite.push($(this).val());
    });
    alert("My favourite movies are: " + favorite.join(", "));
    });
});
</script>
```

Now how can I pass the `favorite` array from `app.blade.php` to my laravel view `create.blade.php`. Thank you

Comment: Very hard to understand what you are asking. Do you mean you want to click some button (`showCBs`?), and without refreshing the page, show some summary of which rows are checked?

Comment: Yes @Don'tPanic, I want a summary of clicked rows. For example, suppose the table has 100 movies, then after clicking 5 movie rows, I want to show that 5 movies in a table next to this big table. After that, I want to give an option for sequence. User will perform all these steps and then will click save button.

Comment: There are many many tutorials and examples on how to update page contents with jQuery. What have you tried? As an example, add a data-attribute to your input with  the movie name, like `data-name='...'`. Then you can iterate over your `favorite` JS array and find the movie names, and write them somewhere. Do some searching, there are so many examples of this stuff.

Comment: Okay, @Don'tPanic I will do some research and will try to implement it. Thanks for the help